# Dates in second column are not rendering properly

Tags: fullcalendar, codeigniter-3

Events which are in full calendar are rendering to previous date.

I have gone through A bunch of things on the net, however I could not find any answers. Any idea would be very helpful to me.

Events code:

```html
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>front_assets/assets/scripts/eventscalenadar.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>front_assets/assets/css/eventcaleadar.css">  

<section>
    <div class="gp blk-lyr opc5">
        <div class="fxd-bg subpage" style="background-image: url(<?= base_url(); ?>front_assets/assets/images/fizicity.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pg-tp text-center">
                <h1 itemprop="headline">Events</h1>

                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>" title="" itemprop="url">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Events</li>
                </ol>
            </div><!-- Page Top -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section  ng-app="events">
    <div class="gp opc7 gry-lyr3 btm-spc50" >
        <div class="fxd-bg" style="background-image: url(<?= base_url(); ?>front_ssets/assets/images/parlx2.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id='wrap' class="resscroll">
                        <div id='calendar'></div>
                        <div style='clear:both'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
          function renderCalendar() {
              var values = [];

              $.ajax({
                      url: '<?= base_url(); ?>' + 'home/get_events',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      type: 'post',
                      success: function (response) {
                           for (var ln = 0; ln < response.length; ln++) {
                                var item1 = {
                                                title : response[ln].title,
                                                start: new Date(response[ln].start_year, response[ln].start_month-1, response[ln].start_date, response[ln].start_hour,response[ln].start_minute,0,0),
                                                end:   new Date(response[ln].start_year, response[ln].start_month-1, response[ln].end_date, response[ln].end_hour,response[ln].end_minute,0,0),
                                                allDay: false,
                                                url   : response[ln].url,
                                                className : 'info', 
                                           };
                                      values.push(item1);
                                 }

                                 console.log(values);

                                 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                    viewDisplay   : function(view) {
                                         var now = new Date(); 
                                         var end = new Date();
                                         end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 11); //Adjust as needed
                                         var cal_date_string = view.start.getMonth()+'/'+view.start.getFullYear();
                                         var cur_date_string = now.getMonth()+'/'+now.getFullYear();
                                         var end_date_string = end.getMonth()+'/'+end.getFullYear();

                      if(cal_date_string == cur_date_string) { $('.fc-button-prev').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
                      else { $('.fc-button-prev').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }

                      if(end_date_string == cal_date_string) { $('.fc-button-next').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
                      else { $('.fc-button-next').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
                    },



                  header: {
                        left: 'title',
                        center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
                        right: 'prev,next today'
                    },
                    firstDay:0, //  1(Monday) this can be changed to 0(Sunday) for the USA system
                    events:values,

                });

            }

        });

     }

      renderCalendar();

});

</script>
```

**Json feed:**

```
0: {title: "Internal testing ANZ eGate", start: Sun Sep 08 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Sun Sep 08 2019 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_register/141", …}
1: {title: "Internal testing ANZ eGate", start: Tue Sep 03 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Tue Sep 03 2019 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_register/146", …}
2: {title: "Internal testing ANZ eGate", start: Sat Sep 07 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Sat Sep 07 2019 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_register/148", …}
3: {title: "Internal testing ANZ eGate", start: Thu Sep 05 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Thu Sep 05 2019 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_register/149", …}
4: {title: "Internal testing ANZ eGate", start: Fri Sep 06 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Fri Sep 06 2019 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_register/150", …}
5: {title: "Anz e-gate test", start: Wed Sep 11 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Wed Sep 11 2019 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_register/156", …}
6: {title: "Title", start: Wed Oct 09 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Wed Oct 09 2019 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), allDay: false, url: "event_reg
```

Comment: Is this the same as your other question, or a separate issue? Please don't post the same issue twice, even with different wording. Consider combining your posts into one if they relate to the same problem

Comment: P.S. If I had to guess based on the sample data I'd say maybe there's a timezone issue.

Comment: Yes this is a timezone issue sir . Thanks for your time